# In React.js, how would I set up a simple global event system to communicate between components?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, components, communication

After toying with React a bit, I think I mostly like it, but there are a couple of things I'm struggling to figure out how to do.  One of those is basic communication between components that are not in a parent-child relationship.

As I understand from the tutorial, most communication is done via a parent-child relationship using states and props, and that seems simple enough.  But when there is no parent-child relationship, the docs recommend [setting up a global event system](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html) and just leave that to me to figure out.  Not really sure what is meant by this.

Let's take the problem I'm working on as an example. I have a `<SearchBar />` component in the navbar of my page and I would like to use this to populate search results in a `<ResultsTab />` component elsewhere on the page.  Trying to relate these via a common parent just isn't practical. So how would I update the ResultsTab with the SearchBar's results? I'm sure I could just do it via jQuery and forget about React, but what is the proper React way to do this?

Comment: Well, the React docs do specify that you could use something like a Flux pattern to achieve communication between components. There are a bunch of Flux implementations that you can use, and it does seem to fit the React way of doing things.

Comment: You can also search for pubsub.

Comment: For data (like your example) you can use flux/backbone. For global events we use pubsub.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook have released a pattern called Flux for this - https://github.com/facebook/flux. It can be very verbose in simple applications, but it works well.

As with all these things, the community is moving *very* fast and making a lot of changes. I recommend getting used to very basic examples, then read https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/the-evolution-of-flux-frameworks-6c16ad26bb31 and try some of the others.

@dan_abramov's https://github.com/gaearon/redux seems very popular at the moment.